# converting Java Tokenizer to a Stream object inorder to take advantage of filtering

Tags: java, file-io, java-8

I am writing some basic file i/o code, and thought i might take advantage of the Java 8 Streams; particularly the filtering. the end goal is to read in a file and tokenize only the applicable lines. the following is my current code:

```
 public void readInFile(String csvFile){

    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    final String csvSplitBy = ",";

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] transaction = line.split(csvSplitBy);
            transactions.add(new QBTransaction(
                    new TransactionDetails(transaction[TRANSACTION_DATE],
                            transaction[TRANSACTION_NUM],
                            transaction[TRANSACTION_NAME],
                            Double.parseDouble(transaction[TRANSACTION_AMOUNT]))));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    transactionServiceImpl.addAll(transactions);
}
```

very boiler plate. here is code using the Stream:

```
public void parseFile(String fileName) {

    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
        stream
                .filter(w -> w.startsWith("Payment"))
                //create object
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to put a tokenizer in the foreach, or maybe output a String object I could feed into another method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two snippets of code you have do not do the same thing but your problem sounds like you are not aware of the [`map(mapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method. This method allows to transform (i.e. map) each Stream element into another element. In this case, we want to map two things:

- Each line into a transaction, which is the line split by a separator
- Each transaction String into a real transaction object

Therefore, we can have  two `map` operations for that:

```
List<QBTransaction> transactions = null;
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
    transactions =
        stream.filter(w -> w.startsWith("Payment"))
              .map(l -> l.split(csvSplitBy))
              .map(t -> new QBTransaction(new TransactionDetails(
                 t[TRANSACTION_DATE],
                 t[TRANSACTION_NUM],
                 t[TRANSACTION_NAME],
                 Double.parseDouble(t[TRANSACTION_AMOUNT])
              )))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
transactionServiceImpl.addAll(transactions);
```

The rest of code collects that into a list and finally calls your service by giving that list as parameter.

Comment: yes, that map class is exactly what i was missing, thanks.